# R.java is automatically deleted when I do "Clean" project. Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this problem and I don't know how to fix it.

When I clean the project and R.java was gone, I don't know how to fix it. I'd try to rebuild it, R.java still not shown. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: R.java is generated at compile-time. If it is not the case it means that you have an error in your res/ folder

Comment: yeah, thanks but after cleaning, it's show me an error in project, and I can't run it without it. I have R.java backup in my files but what happened is, it is editable and cannot be auto-generated.

Comment: check your `res/` folder for errors. What is preventing your `R.java` file to be generated is an issue inside `res/`

Comment: anyway, that's one of the great help. Thank you.. :D